# cope 3x3 matrix from a bigger one

Tags: c++

```
for(int i=0;i<getNumRows();++i)
{
    for(int j=0;j<getNumCols();++j)
    {
        int X = hfilter * threebythree(i,j,getData());
        int Y = vfilter * threebythree(i,j,getData());
        //cout<<X<<","<<Y<<endl;
    setValue(i,j, sqrt(X*X+Y*Y));
    }
}
writeToFile(ofilename);
}

Image Image::threebythree(int globali,int globalj,int**data){
Image neighbor;
neighbor.setNumRows(3);
neighbor.setNumCols(3);
neighbor.AllocateMem();
//this algorithm is wrong here, trying to figure out one.
for(int i=0;i<neighbor.getNumRows();++i)
{
    for(int j=0;j<neighbor.getNumCols();++j)
```

what I am doing here is that I am trying to cut a portion out of the bigger matrix, in this case, what the getData() returns, say, it is 100x100 matrix, I want to cope the a 3x3 neighborhood around each pixel from the bigger matrix to newly created one, the condition is that if the 3x3 neighborhood goes out of the bound in the 100X100 matrix, like the top neighbor of data[0-1][1] is out of bound, the corresponding position in the 3x3 matrix is set to zero. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you refine your example? It seems that you give us an incomplete code. And what do you mean by "wrong"?

Comment: This came up not too long ago on SO. The neat solution was to use 102x102 matrix in which the border values are all zero. Then you don't need any edge handling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to all the trouble of building an Image class, why not use it for `data`?

```
Image Image::threebythree(int globali,int globalj, const Image &data)
{
  Image neighbor;
  neighbor.setNumRows(3);
  neighbor.setNumCols(3);
  neighbor.AllocateMem();

  for(int i=0 ; i<=3 ; ++i)
    for(int j=0 ; j<=3 ; ++j)
    {
      if(i+globali-1 >=0 && j+globalj-1 >=0 &&
         i+globali-1 < data.getNumRows() && j+globalj-1 < data.getNumCols())
        neighbor[i][j] = data[i+globali-1][j+globalj-1];
      else
        neighbor[i][j] = 0;
    }
  return(neighbor);
}
```